# I can't get the webdriver to fill space with text, but i've tried everything on this website

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to input the e-mail address from a config file where the list is stored as keys[] or K.  I have tried to locate the element by xpath then send keys k e-mail but that didnt work.  I tried using action chains to tab to the space.  I tried using the wait clicks like i used for everything else.  I also tried locating by name then send keys and locating by class name send keys.  nothing seems to be working.

```
from Config import keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def order(k):

    email_tab = 2 #Number of times to hit tab for email

    # Load the Driver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\ezliv\Desktop\ShopBot1\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(k['product_url'])

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Choose the bottle via xpath
    
    #bottle = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="thumb-bbt2020package"]/div/div[1]/div/div/img')))
    bottle = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="thumb-biereblanche"]/div/div[1]/div/div/img')))
    bottle.click()
    
    wait
    
    #Adding the item to the cart

    add_to_cart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sqs-add-to-cart-button-inner')))
    add_to_cart.click()
    
    # Going to the cart
    
    enter_cart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'custom-cart-button')))
    enter_cart.click()
    
    wait
    
    driver.get(k['checkout_url'])
    
    wait
    
    # Going to checkout screen
    
    checkout_cart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sqs-editable-button CheckoutButton-checkoutButton-3yWY2 checkout-button')))
    checkout_cart.click()
    
    wait
    
    #Enter the email
    
    actions = ActionChains(driver) 
    actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * email_tab)
    actions.perform()
    #email_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
    wait
```

{keys = { "product_url" : "sideprojectbrewing.com/shop?category=Beer+Release", "checkout_url" : "sideprojectbrewing.com/checkout", }

Comment: maybe element is inside `<iframe>` and then browser treats it as separated page and you have to use `driver.switch_to.frame(...)`. If you want better help then always show real URL so we could open it in browser and test problem.

Comment: code better always put it question - it will be more readable and more peoplbe will see it.

Comment: I don't see code which you use to get field for email - maybe you use wrong function.

Comment: code works for me when I remove lines `checkout_cart = ...` and `checkout_cart.click()` because using `driver.get(k['checkout_url'])` you are already on `checkout` page and you don't have to search `checkout` button.

Comment: In this particular iteration i tried tabbing down to the space for email.  Like i said in the question i also tried to xpath to the spot and send_keys the email.  didnt work.  I also tried to find by name or by class and then send keys but it didnt work

Comment: in this code problem is NOT email field but button `checkout` - you use `get()` to load page with `email` so you don't need to search button `checkout` and click it - when you try to get button `checkout` then it can't find it because it was on previous page (before using `get(k['checkout_url'])`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code problem is not `email` field but button `checkout`.

You use two different methods to load page with `checkout`.

First you use

```
get(k['checkout_url'])
```

and later you use

```
checkout_cart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sqs-editable-button.CheckoutButton-checkoutButton-3yWY2.checkout-button')))
checkout_cart.click()
```

and this makes problem. You have to use one of them, not both. After using first method second method search button on wrong page.

---

**By the way:**

If you use `class` to search elements then there is one problem with mulitclasses like `'sqs-editable-button CheckoutButton-checkoutButton-3yWY2 checkout-button'`. `Selenium`converts it to CSS selector but it treats this string like one class and it adds `.` only before beginning of this string

```
.sqs-editable-button CheckoutButton-checkoutButton-3yWY2 checkout-button
```

but it should put `.` also between all names

```
.sqs-editable-button.CheckoutButton-checkoutButton-3yWY2.checkout-button
```

so you have to put `.` between names manually (but don't add at the beginning)

```
sqs-editable-button.CheckoutButton-checkoutButton-3yWY2.checkout-button
```

so you will have

```
checkout_cart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sqs-editable-button.CheckoutButton-checkoutButton-3yWY2.checkout-button')))                                                                           
checkout_cart.click()
```

---

Code working for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def order(k):

    email_tab = 2 #Number of times to hit tab for email

    # Load the Driver
    print('main page')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(k['product_url'])

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Choose the bottle via xpath
    print('bottle page')
    
    #bottle = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="thumb-bbt2020package"]/div/div[1]/div/div/img')))
    bottle = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="thumb-biereblanche"]/div/div[1]/div/div/img')))
    bottle.click()
    
    #Adding the item to the cart
    print('add to cart')

    add_to_cart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sqs-add-to-cart-button-inner')))
    add_to_cart.click()
    
    # Going to the cart
    print('go to cart')
    
    enter_cart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'custom-cart-button')))
    enter_cart.click()
    
    #print('go to checkout')
    #driver.get(k['checkout_url'])
    
    # Going to checkout screen
    print('go to checkout')
    
    checkout_cart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sqs-editable-button.CheckoutButton-checkoutButton-3yWY2.checkout-button')))                                                                           
    checkout_cart.click()
    
    #Enter the email
    print('email')
    
    actions = ActionChains(driver) 
    actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * email_tab)
    actions.send_keys('hello@world.com')
    actions.perform()
    #email_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
    import time
    time.sleep(3)
    
# --- main ---
    
keys = {
    "product_url": "https://sideprojectbrewing.com/shop?category=Beer+Release", 
    "checkout_url": "https://sideprojectbrewing.com/checkout",
} 

order(keys)
```

Comment: This worked great and actually the next step was to try to paste text in an IFRAME field so i'll have to start learning about that now just like you had mentioned.